# Jenkins NoSuchFileException when using multiple repositories

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running into an issue where I keep getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException when I try to load a Jenkins file from a repo.

I am making use of 2 git repos.

**repo1.git** contains the following files:

**test.jenkinsfile**
**initialemail.groovy**
**statusemail.groovy**

**repo2.git** contains the following files: 
All the files for the build/deploy stages of the pipeline (hence we do the explicit checkout in the pipeline code below).

The configuration of the Jenkins pipeline is as follows: 
Definition: Pipeline Script from SCM 
**SCM:** Git
**Repository url:** git@gitlab.com:test/repo1.git
**Credentials:** test
**Branches to build:** testbranch
**Script path:** jenkins/test.jenkinsfile

The **test.jenkinsfile** is as follows:

```
//create an empty map to capture the stage status
def stageStatusMap = [:]

pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        AWS_CREDENTIALS = credentials('Test')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Send Initial Email') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def initialemailsender = load 'jenkins/initialemail.groovy'
                    initialemailsender.sendemail()
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                    credentialsId: 'test',
                    url: 'git@gitlab.com:test/repo2.git'
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                //some build steps here from the Docker files in repo2.git
            }
            post {
                success {
                    script {
                        stageStatusMap['Build'] = 'Success'
                    }
                }
                failure {
                    script {
                        stageStatusMap['Build'] = 'Failed'
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    post {
        always {
            script {
                    //Load the statusemail from repo1.git 
                    statusemail = load 'jenkins/statusemail.groovy'
                    statusemail.sendemail(stageStatusMap)
                    echo "test"
            }
            cleanWs()
            echo 'Cleaned up the workspace and finished executing pipeline!'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the pipeline, I get the following error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data/jenkins/workspace/Test/jenkins/statusemail.groovy
```

I believe the final email file (**statusemail.groovy**) is not being found because after the checkout step is finished, the context is now **repo2.git** which obviously doesn't have the **statusemail.groovy** file.

One solution was to check out the **repo1.git** again and then run the commands and that works. However, I am looking for a better solution to not have to do that for code maintainability purposes.

**Other solutions I have tried but that have not worked:**

1. Defining the statusemail = load 'jenkins/statusemailappended.groovy' at the start of the pipeline right by where I have the stageStatusMap[:] defined. That doesn't work because it expects this definition to be within a particular stage of the pipeline.
2. Defining the statusemail = load 'jenkins/statusemailappended.groovy' within the **Send Initial Email** stage. This also doesn't work because I believe that statusemail is no longer available during the final post {} block where it is being called.

Any solution which doesn't require me to have to checkout the code again from **repo1.git** to access the **statusemail.groovy** file in the post{} section would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you aren't doing a lightweight checkout of repo1. Then you can consider checking out repo2 to a completely different folder by closing the block with `dir` this:

```
stage('Checkout') {
    steps {
        dir(repo2) {
            git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'test',
                url: 'git@gitlab.com:test/repo2.git'
        }
   }
}
```

Of course this means that any other work you do that uses files from repo2 will now be inside `$WORKSPACE/repo2`, so you will have to adjust your code accordingly (by wrapping your "Build" stage in `dir(repo2)`. But this means that your repo1 code will be preserved. If it still doesn't work, try:

```
statusemail = load '${workspace}/jenkins/statusemail.groovy'
```

If still the same result, echo the output of `ls` and `pwd` to verify which folder you are in, and which folders exist.

Comment: Thanks! I already made sure I didn't do a lightweight checkout of repo1.

What worked for me is to checkout code for repo2 in a separate folder using dir and then using dir in the subsequent steps where repo2 was in question. Once I made this change, the statusemail.groovy file was found correctly when it got to that final step! Thanks for the help :)